# How can I specify the starting value for a range when using the v-for directive in Vue.js v2.x?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I'm working on printing out the page numbers a user may click on for a pager component in Vue.js. I see that the docs clearly say v-for can be used for a range:

> v-for can also take an integer. In this case it will repeat the
> template that many times.
>
> `<div>   <span v-for="n in 10">{{ n }} </span> </div>`
>
> Result:
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Per https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range

I have not found anyway to specify the starting value for n. It seems that it starts at 1 and increments by 1 until 10.

Is there anyway to start n at, say, 5?

It almost seems like I'll need to create a method or computed property that will return an array of the exact values I want iterated in place of the static 10.

Anyone have any other thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to start a `v-for` at *n*.

However, starting at an offset is as simple as adding the offset to your value and then stopping when you hit max.

```html
<div>
  <template v-for="n in max">
    <span v-if="n + offset <= max">{{ n + offset }} </span>
  </template>
</div>
```

If you need more control, a `computed` property is most definitely the way to go, as it will provide you full control over whatever you're iterating over.

```html
<div>
  <span v-for="n in computedArr">{{ n }} </span>
</div>
```

```js
  computed: {
    computedArr() {
      let arr = [];
      for (var i = this.offset; i <= this.max; i++)
        arr.push(i);
      return arr;
    },
    ...
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Comment: Would it not be better to use `arr.push[i]` instead of `arr[i] = i`. With the latter you are starting to write into the array on a position which is i and not 0 and resulting in an array length which is higher than its actual entries.

Comment: @Stefan You're totally right; for this particular functionality, it doesn't seem to matter, but doing it with `arr[i] = [i]` could lead to weird bugs/ behavior down the road since the resulting array's length will indeed be `max + 1` instead of `max + 1 - offset`, as you'd expect. I'll swap it for `push()` in the example.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to define your own helper function to generate the sequence:

```js
Vue.prototype.$range = function *(start, end, step = 1) {
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
    yield i
  }
}

new Vue({ el: '#app' })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="i of $range(5, 10)">
    {{ i }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div-for="index in Array(y).fill(x).map((x, y) => x + y)" :key="index">{{ index }}</div>
```

`x` is the start position and `y` is the count of subsequent numbers.

so this...

```
Array(6).fill(5).map((x, y) => x + y)
```

will should you an array like`[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` to traverse.

I think this should be a more efficient answer.